# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'headers'

Tags: javascript, python, django, http

I have these two codes, i'm working with  django, it's a request that asks for a specific project, and the python is supposed to give it back with the return function

```py
def project(request):
    request_body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    queryID = request_body['queryID']

    with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'projects//') + queryID + ".json", 'r') as f:
        response = json.loads(f.read())
        return response
```

```
const url = "/project"
let id_request = {"queryID":projectID}

let data = fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: "same-origin",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "network/json",
        "Content-Type": "network/json",
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(id_request)
    }
    )
    .then(response=>response.text())
    .then(data=>{ 
        console.log(data); 
    })
```

But when reading the json file I want to return, it throws an error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'headers'
```

Comment: You must return a `Response` from a view, not a plain dict.

Comment: So it's crashing on `json.loads(f.read())`?- Might be a Json error?? Have you double checked that 'headers' in actually in the json (I don't even see you trying to fetch that key)

Answer (score 1):

In Django, you shall return a response not Dict

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'projects//') + queryID + ".json", 'r') as f:
    return HttpResponse(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

The view is supposed to return a `HttpResponse`, in this case you likely want to use a [**`JsonResponse`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects), so:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


def project(request):
    request_body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    queryID = request_body['queryID']
    with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'projects//') + queryID + '.json') as f:
        return JsonResponse(json.load(f))
```

beware that using allowing to work with an *arbitrary path* is however *very* unsafe. Imagine that the person makes a request with `../../../../../secret.txt`, then one could try to obtain a secret file that the user is not supposed to see. This is a school example of an insecure system.